# Upgrade SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I had SQL Server 2008 Express R2 With Advanced Services installed. I also have SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition installed

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition to a new reporting engine - I had management studio selected in the install options...

But Management Studio remains the Express version and I am not able to connect to reporting servers analysis services

I've tried every possible route though the SQL Server installer and none of them will allow me to change, remove or add Management Studio.

I'd dearly love to avoid uninstalling and reinstalling the whole lot, if anybody knows a way to update Management Studio alone I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanksfully I don'e specifically need to test against SQL Express.

I upgraded my Express instance to Developer edition.

Once this was done, When I went to Add Features - the checkbox for Advanced Features for Management studio - which had previously been read-only, could now be checked.

I checked it, completed the wizard and I now have a working Management Studio